# How to add CRYPTOFINANCE() into Google-Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to fetch prices for cryptocurrencies such as `Litecoin`.

[`CRYPTOFINANCE()`](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/cryptofinance/1068702502555) function used to work but now seems like it does not anymore, saying `Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.`. Its sad that something useful it not working anymore. I was just wondering could there be any hack to make it work, or is there any alternative for `CRYPTOFINANCE()?

`GOOGLEFINANCE()` is able to fetched price for `BTCUSD` and `ETHUSD` but cannot fetch price for `LTCUSD` and other cryptocurrencies.

Link: https://blog.sheetgo.com/finance-processes/how-to-use-cryptofinance-add-on-for-google-sheets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CRYPTOFINANCE()** is a custom function made via Google Apps Script. You can try updating your script by going to Google Sheets -> `Tools` -> `Script Editor`. You should see an existing script there if you've been working with the same sheet or if you are now using a new sheet, copy and paste the code from [cryptofinance.ai](https://cryptofinance.ai/docs/getting-started-with-cryptofinance/) to your script editor(just follow the instructions from the site) and your formula should work.

I tried it on my end and it seems that the CRYPTOFINANCE() function is working properly.

[image]